# Linux bash weave two text files into one alternative line using all available lines

Tags: bash, shell, sed, merge, cat

I am looking to merge two text files into one,
where all the lines from one text file become odd line numbers
and the other file becomes even line numbers
such as to weave the files together

input1.txt

```
1, 267, Note_on_c, 0, 67, 100
1, 758, Note_on_c, 0, 58, 100
1, 1248, Note_on_c, 0, 79, 100
1, 1739, Note_on_c, 0, 52, 100
```

input2.txt

```
1, 368, Note_off_c, 0, 67, 127
1, 936, Note_off_c, 0, 58, 127
1, 1415, Note_off_c, 0, 79, 127
1, 1917, Note_off_c, 0, 52, 127
```

and need to combine these text files to create the following output

```
1, 267, Note_on_c, 0, 67, 100
1, 368, Note_off_c, 0, 67, 127
1, 758, Note_on_c, 0, 58, 100
1, 936, Note_off_c, 0, 58, 127
1, 1248, Note_on_c, 0, 79, 100
1, 1415, Note_off_c, 0, 79, 127
1, 1739, Note_on_c, 0, 52, 100
1, 1917, Note_off_c, 0, 52, 127
```

so I am looking to merge these files in the true since of the word weave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `sed`'s `R` command:

```
sed 'R input2.txt' input1.txt
```

Output:

```
1, 267, Note_on_c, 0, 67, 100
1, 368, Note_off_c, 0, 67, 127
1, 758, Note_on_c, 0, 58, 100
1, 936, Note_off_c, 0, 58, 127
1, 1248, Note_on_c, 0, 79, 100
1, 1415, Note_off_c, 0, 79, 127
1, 1739, Note_on_c, 0, 52, 100
1, 1917, Note_off_c, 0, 52, 127
```

From `man sed`:

> `R filename`:
> Append  a  line read from filename.  Each invocation of the command reads a line from the file.  This is a GNU
> extension.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative would be using `paste` with a newline as delimiter

```sh
paste -d '\n' input1.txt input2.txt
```

```
1, 267, Note_on_c, 0, 67, 100
1, 368, Note_off_c, 0, 67, 127
1, 758, Note_on_c, 0, 58, 100
1, 936, Note_off_c, 0, 58, 127
1, 1248, Note_on_c, 0, 79, 100
1, 1415, Note_off_c, 0, 79, 127
1, 1739, Note_on_c, 0, 52, 100
1, 1917, Note_off_c, 0, 52, 127
```

From `man paste`:

> Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE